# CollectionView error in current ember-latest?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, collectionview

I made some tests with ember-0.9.8.1.js and the following code works as expected.
After that I read about the router and that the router - code is only available in the current ember-latest.js (16.06.2012).
I test the code below with this version.
The problem is the list is rendered:

```
  <div id="ember143" class="ember-view">
    <ul id="PersonList" class="ember-view ListBox">
      <li id="ember179" class="ember-view">
       <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
       <script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      </li>
      <li id="ember183" class="ember-view">
        <script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
        <script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      </li>
      <li id="ember187" class="ember-view">
        <script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
        <script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      </li>
      <li id="ember191" class="ember-view">
        <script id="metamorph-3-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
        <script id="metamorph-3-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
```

but is empty.
Something with the

template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{content.name}}"),

is not working correctly or some syntax aspects has changed.

The code line

console.log("content:",this.get('content'));

in the click handler shows, that the right content is there, but

Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{content.name}}"),

will not render the content.

Is this a bug ???

Javascript Code:

```
 var App = Em.Application.create({

    ready: function(){
        App.personListController.getData();
    }
    });


    // Model Objects

    App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
      name: null,
      myTickets: null,
      selected: false
    });


    // Liste von Personen anlegen

    App.personListController = Ember.ArrayController.create({

    getData: function(){

        $.get('json/person.json', function(data) {
            var personList = Ember.A([]);
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                var p = App.Person.create({
                    'name': item.name,
                    'myTickets': null,
                    'selected': false
                });
                personList.pushObject(p);
            });
            App.personListController.set('content', personList);
        })
    },
    resetSelection: function(){
        App.personListController.content.forEach(function(item){
            item.set('selected',false);
        })
    },
    selectedPerson: null
    });


    App.PersonList = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
      tagName: 'ul',
      contentBinding: 'App.personListController.content',
      classNames: ['ListBox'],
      mouseenter: function(event){
        console.log("PersonList.content:",this.get('content'));
      },

    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{content.name}}"),
        classNameBindings: ['selected:selected'],
        selectedBinding: 'content.selected',
        click:
            function(event){
                App.personListController.resetSelection() ;
                this.setPath('content.selected',true);
                App.personListController.set('selectedPerson',this.get('content'));
                console.log("ItemViewInfo selected:",this.getPath('content.selected'));
                console.log("content:",this.get('content'));
                //this.set('isSelected',true);
            }
       })
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
   {{#view App.PersonList id="PersonList"}}

   {{/view}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the lookup context for a `view` changed in the latest commits. Now you have to prepend `view` if you want to lookup a property on the `view`. See documentation updates in commit [8a6c6](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/8a6c62ac1960dd8590f2128e7aad737404234506).

The template therefore changes to

```js
template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{view.content.name}}")
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/DsdHU/.

Tom Dale has a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/2494968) which explains the changes further.

Answer (score 0):

The latest-ember.js (aswell as ember-1.0.pre.js) does not include handlebars anymore, you have to include it by your own.

You also have to start the event-loop yourself now:
**!! -> seems like you don't need that anymore.. !!**

```
App.initialize();
```

..the associated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aGMzD/